# overloaded stream insertion operator errors, won't compile

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload `operator<<` for my `Graph` class but I keep getting various errors:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
```

I have the prototype for `operator<<` placed right above the `Graph` class definition. `operator<<`'s definition is at the very bottom of the file. Do the errors have something to do with header guards?

Here's `Graph.h`:

```
#ifndef GRAPH
#define GRAPH

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include "GraphException.h"
#include "Edge.h"

using namespace std;

template <class VertexType>
ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, const Graph<VertexType>& graph );

/** An adjacency list representation of an undirected,
 * weighted graph. */

template <class VertexType>
class Graph
{
    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, const Graph& graph );
   // stuff

}  


template <class VertexType>
ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, const Graph<VertexType>& graph )
{
    return out;
}

#endif GRAPH
```

and here's `main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Graph.h"

using namespace std;

const unsigned MAX_NUM_VERTICES = 9;

int main()
{
    // create int graph:

Graph<int> iGraph( MAX_NUM_VERTICES );

    // add vertices and edges

    cout << iGraph;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: People will be more helpful in the future if you try to make an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). A good side effect of thinking this way is that you’ll likely figure out your problem before having to post the question.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of SSCCE. I edited out all the stuff I felt was extraneous. Thing is, I'm usually not the best arbiter of what is extraneous and what isn't.

Comment: It's a graph of ints. Edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `operator<<` is missing a declaration for `Graph`. One solution is to declare the class before the `operator<<` declaration:

```
template <class VertexType>
class Graph;
```

Or you can omit the declaration of `operator<<` outside the class entirely, as a `friend` declaration constitutes a nonmember declaration of `operator<<` as well.

Comment: Removing operator<<'s declaration yielded another error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: @JamesGold: Sorry, I don’t have Visual Studio on hand. Both of my suggestions work in Apple Clang 4.2 and GCC 4.2.1. You might also try `template<class V> friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Graph<V>&);`—that is, declare that `operator<<` is a friend of `Graph<VertexType>` for any `V`, not just for `VertexType`.